# What movie ends with a character phoning themselves in the past, and then disappearing?

Tags: story-identification, movie

There was a film I saw 5–10 years ago. It was English language, but I don’t know what country it came from.

The two characters I can remember were male & female, probably late teens or in their twenties.

The only event I can remember from it was near the end when one of the characters had a machine that they put the receiver of a telephone onto, which enabled them to dial a telephone that they had passed sometime earlier that day.

That character told their past self something which changes history. Then that character is seen on the floor in pain before they disappear.

Does anyone have any ideas what this film is called?

Comment: Roughly speaking, when did you see this? What language was it in? What gender(s) were the main characters? Can you describe any of the characters?

Comment: I think I seen it probably 5-10 years ago. It was a English language film (but I don't know if its American or Canadian). The two main characters I can remember where male & female, probably late teens or in there 20s or thereabouts.

Comment: When you say "disappear" do you mean they actually vanish before the audience's eyes, or just that they run off and go into hiding or something? Also, do you remember if the character seen on the floor in pain was the past self or the slightly older version who had called the past self?

Comment: Sounds like primer,  but I don't have enough details to confirm the scene.  Anyone?

Comment: From what I can remember, when they're on the floor they faded while in view of the camera. Also I think the 'older' versions of the characters are the same age as the 'younger' versions because the story takes place over a day or several days/ weeks, but I'm not sure.